# Доступ к полю класса из объекта, который содержится в этом же классе. WPF страничное приложение

Tags: c#, wpf, ооп, mvvm

Нужно получить доступ к полю класса из объекта, который находится в этом же классе. SelectedPageViewModel = LogInViewModel. При успешной регистрации должен изменяться SelectedPageViewModel на другую вью модель. Все создается в DataContext главного окна.

```
internal class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private IPageViewModel _selectedPageViewModel;
    private IList<IPageViewModel> _pageViewModels;
    public IList<IPageViewModel> PageViewModels
    {
        get => _pageViewModels;
        set => Set(ref _pageViewModels, value); 
    }
    public IPageViewModel SelectedPageViewModel
    {
        get => _selectedPageViewModel;
        set
        {
            Set(ref _selectedPageViewModel, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title));
        }
    }
    public string Title => $"MultiPage demo - {SelectedPageViewModel?.Title}";

    private Visibility _intro;
    public Visibility IntroVisability
    {
        get => _intro;
        set => Set(ref _intro, value);
    }

    #region Commands main window
    public ICommand InitCommand { get; }
    private bool CanInitCommand(object parameter) => true;
    private void OnInitCommand(object parameter)
    {
        IntroVisability = Visibility.Collapsed;
        SelectedPageViewModel = PageViewModels.First();
    }
    #endregion
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        InitCommand = new LamdaCommand(OnInitCommand, CanInitCommand);
    }
}
```

```
internal class LogInViewModel : ViewModel, IPageViewModel
{
    private bool _typeLogIn = true;
    public bool TypeLogIn
    {
        get => _typeLogIn;
        set => _typeLogIn = value;
    }
    #region Lines text boxes(Login, password)
    private string? _username = null;
    public string? Username
    {
        get => _username;
        set => Set(ref _username, value);
    }

    private string? _password = null;
    public string? Password
    {
        get => _password;
        set => Set(ref _password, value);
    }
    #endregion
    #region Commands main window
    public ICommand LogInCommand { get; }
    private bool CanLogInCommand(object parameter) => true;
    private void OnLogInCommand(object parameter)
    {
        UserController uc = new UserController();

        if (uc.LogIn(_username, _password))
        {
        
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No yeah");
    }
    #endregion
    public string Title => "LogIn";

    public LogInViewModel()
    {
        LogInCommand = new LamdaCommand(OnLogInCommand, CanLogInCommand);
    }
}
```

```
public partial class App : Application
```

{
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
base.OnStartup(e);

```
    new MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            PageViewModels = new List<IPageViewModel>
            {
                new LogInViewModel(),
                new ProfileViewModel()
            }
        }
    }.Show();
}
```

}

Comment: Проблема в чем? Передавайте ссылку через конструктор одной VM в другую, и вызывайте что вам надо, можете делегировать эту проблему отдельному классу, который уже будете "внедрять" в нужные классы также, через конструктор.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно в иерархических структурах данных заводят поля (или свойства) `Object Parent`, которые в конструкторе инициализируют ссылкой на верхний объект:

```
class A {
  TChild child;
  ... addChild() {
        child = new TChild(this);
...
class TChild {
  public Object Parent;
  public TChild(Object p) {
        Parent = p;
...
```